# Laravel 5 namespacing issue

Tags: php, laravel, namespaces

I have an app in which I have moved all controller/model/repo/service logic outside the native Laravel app folder. I have `Acme` folder in root and I have added following to composer:

```
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Acme\\": "acme/"
    }
```

`AccountController` is namespaced like this:

```
<?php namespace Acme\Account\Controller;
```

And the issue I am having is in this line:

```
urlContainer['userAjax'] = "{!! RoutingService::actionAjax('Account\Controller\AccountController@getUserAjax') !!}";
```

I am receiving error message that:

```
Action \Acme\Account\Controller\AccountController@getUserAjax not defined
```

Controller exists, method exists and route exists. I can't seem to see what is causing the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I assume the problem is the location of your file.

Your configuration says every class in the folder acme/ is in the `Acme\` namespace. Your controller's full name is `Acme\Account\Controller\AccountController`. According to PSR-4 the location should be:

```
acme/Account/Controller/AccountController.php
```

If that is not the case you can change your autoloader settings as follows:

```
"Acme\\Account\\": "acme/"
```

or move your file.

edit: Another possibility is that the `namespace` in your controller contains a typo.

Comment: Is the prs4 autoloader case sensitive?

Comment: It depends on your OS (linux: yes, windows: no, mac: maybe), but I would treat it as such.

Comment: I just noticed you are probably wondering because the lowercase a in the namespace. That was just a typo, sorry

Comment: I have capitalized first letter, path is fine, no typos. Maybe something else is breaking it

Comment: Sorry, I reverted that change. The first letter should be acme, as that is the folder name and all folders in there should be uppercased and match exactly the namespace. If you don't want that you should probably use a different autoloader like classmap.

Comment: The strange thing is, I did a route dump, and the same one which is written under `Action` is the one which is listed as errored out

Comment: It works if I use complete path like `\Acme\Account...`